# Integrating react native app with smooch api

Tags: android, react-native, smooch

I am trying to integrate my react native app with smooch.io following this [instructions](https://github.com/smooch/react-native-smooch/blob/master/README.md). I have succesfully installing the module and configure MainApplication.java. Now i have problem when trying to show the conversation screen. Where should i put `Smooch.show()` in my react native app? Here is my index.android.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  View
} from 'react-native';

import Smooch from 'react-native-smooch';

export default class SmoochTest extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    Smooch.show();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  // some style
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SmoochTest', () => SmoochTest);
```

Comment: use it in componentDidMount()

Comment: @SagarChavada i did it and get **undefined is not a function (evaluating '_reactNativeSmooch2.default.show()')** please check my edited question.

Comment: you should generate issue on github.. you will get quick ans. owner of this lib will reach you soon..

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue - did you link it? `react-native link react-native-smooch`. That solved it for me.